# php execute script random times on date range

Tags: php

What i need to archive is to be able to execute certain script (code) random times (1.5) based on a date range.

**Example:**

Define date range:

```
From 2022-09-01 to 2022-09-15
```

The script need to be executed a random times (1.5 or doesn't matter) for each date as defined.

```
So for example: on 1 Sep the script will be executed 4 times (random nr)
So for example: on 2 Sep the script will be executed 2 times (random nr)
So for example: on 3 Sep the script will be executed 1 times (random nr)
...
So for example: on 5 Sep the script will be executed 5 times (random nr)
```

**Any suggestion will be really appreciated**

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) You need a script to invoke the script (at random times).  Q: Were you planning on writing this "master script" in PHP?  Or use [cron](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm)? Do you want just one script, that runs in continuous loop, and "sleeps" between invocations?  2) You need a "data store" to keep track of a) the time period, and b) how many times the script has already run.  Q: Were you planning on using a database?

Comment: The script needs to run 1 time and the code inside the loop will do some updates on a database. Instead of changing the date manually for a large range of dates, the idea is to define the time range so it will do the updates on each date. Is not planned to run on cron job but manually when needed.

Comment: If I understand correctly then the dates are completely irrelevant here. You simply want to execute your script a random times each day in that period. Easiest is to use a cron job executing the script every x minutes in the period. At the beginning of the script you now chose a random number and compare it against a threshold. If it is lower, the script terminates, if it is higher the script executes. Now all that is left is to chose the threshold such that in average the script is executed x times a day, where x is the average number you want.